# PrestaShop - Get orders for logged in user

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

How to fetch user order history programmatically in a custom module via $this->context?

```
$this->context->link->getOrderHistory(); ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static getCustomerOrders function from the Order class:

```
Order::getCustomerOrders((int)$this->context->customer->id))
```

It will return an array of the customer orders

Comment: Apologies, didn't specify PrestaShop version.
Will this code work in version 1.7?

Comment: It should. 1.7 has the same function in the Order class with the same parameters.